# Moq Xunit test setup to return IDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I'm trying to moq setup for a method:

```
IDictionary<string, string> MyMethod(myObject request);
```

In my test case, moq setup is as:

```
mockServiceAdapter.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(TestData.getmyObject)).Returns(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key1", "val1" } });
```

when my test executes `MyMethod()`, it is returning **null** but I am expecting `{ "key1", "val1" }`. Where I am missing.

can you please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem could be with the parameter being passed in to the mocked method(MyMethod). Instead of passing the object "TestData.getmyObject", You can try with the below code snippet.

```
mockServiceAdapter.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<ClassName>())).Returns(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key1", "val1" } });
```